# Webapi controller and Objectdatasource

Tags: c#, angularjs, objectdatasource, devextreme, webapi2

I want to move step by step from webforms to a client application based on z angularjs or devextreme. At the moment I am using an objectdatasource and load data over a kind of controller that is marked as dataobject. 
Since I want to go step by step,  I want to know if it is possible to first convert my current controllers to webapi controllers and bind the objectdatasources to the webapi methods. 
So zgqt in the next step I already have the data access interface.

Comment: You mean a WinForms ObjectDataSource? That's not going to work with Web Api. You will need a service layer in between your controller and database such as Entity Framework or something you maybe craft in ADO.NET. Entity Framework has tools that will let you reverse engineer your database into starting classes.

Comment: Web forms has object data source. But as Steve Greene said, you'll need to create a data access / service layer. This isn't the place for that though.